# Php error MongoDB

Tags: php, apache, mongodb

I try to install mongo in my PC (windows 7). I have wamp 2.2.11 with php 5.3.0

I follow the instruction from.

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

But it is not working with the code

```
$m = new MongoClient();
echo "Connection to database successfully";
```

Giving Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found.

I have search here

[MongoClient not found in WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288025/mongoclient-not-found-in-wamp)

[MongoDB not working with PHP on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317101/mongodb-not-working-with-php-on-wamp)

[WAMPServer Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21785995/wampserver-fatal-error-class-mongo-not-found)

And some other but nothing happen. I have add php_mongo.dll file at 
wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\ext

And change php.ini at wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin

But it is not working.

Please help.

Comment: Did you restart your web-server?

Comment: yes...I have restart more than once

Comment: What do see in your `phpinfo()` about MongoDB?

Comment: no,, nothing about MangoDB

Comment: It means that you have another web-server that is configured with enabled Mongo-lib, but you never use it. Or you did something wrong while installation.

Comment: @user3419778 Can you check the value of extension_dir directive in your php.ini ?

Comment: It is c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/